Flutter ERRORS IN DEPENDENCIES AND GRADEL
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO KE5k in debug mode...
Conflict detected between Android Studio Java version and Gradle version, upgrading Gradle version from 5.6.2 to 7.6.1.
Upgrading gradle-wrapper.properties
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'E:\Flutter Projects\prohandover (1)\prohandover\android\app\build.gradle' line: 29

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.



Could not get unknown property 'versionCode' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 31s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
To run my code.
